# Two way binding for angular strap

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I'm fairly new to angularjs and am using angular strap to use some of their features like aside.

So basically I have a function like this:

> ```
>   $scope.myAside = function() {
>     $aside({
>         title: 'My Title', 
>         show: true, 
>         animation: 'am-slide-left', 
>         placement:'left',
>         contentTemplate: 'views/aside.html'
>     });
> };
> ```

and I wanted to know how to use the two binding to get 'show' to display on the page. I basically wanted something like this on the page:

> The aside is open: {{myAside.show}}

I read through their setup but couldn't find anything about two binding and how to know if the aside modal is open or not.

Here is the plugin with the documentation about aside. http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/asides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `{{ myAside.$scope.$isShown }}`

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/f7qRgTOCqLDQRIBhUHtL?p=preview) showing how this works.

Comment: Hmm.. I use that and it works.. Do you have a plnkr you could share?

Comment: I have added a plnkr to my answer showing this working

Comment: I saw yours worked but mine gets stuck at 'true' and doesn't change back to 'false.' Since I'm new at this, it seems like something fundamental that I am missing. What does the $promise achieve? I didn't have that in my original code.

Comment: Can you check the version of Angular you are using? I can reproduce the issue you describe using v1.3 but not v1.4 - can you make sure you are using v1.4 of Angular ?

Comment: That was it! Who are you magical keithm and would you like a job on this startup!? Haha! Thanks!